# What action do I need to take, if any, regarding these Flatpak errors?

Tags: 20.04, updates, environment-variables, flatpak

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and just ran a Flatpak update (vers 1.12.7).  There were two errors. The first one (re: `Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime`) has shown up randomly lately, but the second one is new. What action do I need to take if any?

```
  eddie@hp-laptop:~$ flatpak update
        
         Looking for updates…
        Info: org.freedesktop.Sdk//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
           The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version
        Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
           The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version
        Info: org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default//19.08 is end-of-life, with reason:
           The Freedesktop SDK 19.08 runtime is no longer supported as of September 1, 2021. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported version
        
         1.     com.play0ad.zeroad.Locale   stable  u   flathub < 114 bytes (partial)
         2.     com.play0ad.zeroad  stable  u   flathub < 1.7 GB
         3.     org.mozilla.firefox.Locale  stable  u   flathub < 45.5 MB (partial)
         4.     org.mozilla.firefox stable  u   flathub < 87.4 MB
        
    Updating 1/4…
    Updating 1/4…                        0%  0 bytes/s
    Updating 1/4… ████████████████████ 100%
    Updating 2/4…
    Updating 2/4…                        0%  0 bytes/s
    Updating 2/4… ▏                      1%
    Updating 2/4… █████████████▊        69%
    Updating 2/4… ████████████████      80%
    Updating 2/4… █████████████████▊    89%  16.0 MB/s
    Updating 2/4… █████████████████▊    89%  20.5 MB/s
    Updating 2/4… ██████████████████▌   93%  25.3 MB/s
    Updating 2/4… ███████████████████▏  96%  13.2 MB/s
    Updating 2/4… ████████████████████ 100%  13.2 MB/s
    Updating 3/4…
    Updating 3/4…                        0%  0 bytes/s
    Updating 3/4… ▊                      4%
    Updating 3/4… ███████████████▌      78%
    Updating 3/4… ███████████████████▊  99%
    Updating 3/4… ████████████████████ 100%  6.2 MB/s
    Updating 4/4…
    Updating 4/4…                        0%  0 bytes/s
    Updating 4/4… ████████████████████ 100%
        
        Note that '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share' is not in the search path
        set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS
        environment variables, so applications may not
        be able to find it until you set them. The
        directories currently searched are:
        
        - /root/.local/share
        - /usr/local/share/
        - /usr/share/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one or more flatpak applications that continue to rely on  older flatpak runtimes that are not anymore supported. These applications should be updated by the developer, or by the community that prepared the flatpak (not always the developper).

There is little you can do yourself, except

- Filling the issue to the maintainer of the flatpak
- Wait until it is fixed or stop using that flatpak

What you experience is a drawback of the containerized application formats. Outdated libraries with security issues can remain in use in applications that are not properly updated. In a traditional system, libraries are maintained by the distro-maintainers, so vulnerable libraries are systematically replaced. With containerized applications, that responsibility lies with the developers, so is decentralized.

In this case with flatpak, it is noticed because the program relies on a shared run time. If all needed libraries would have been packed within the application's flatpak itself, the issue would remain unnoticed. The issue is alleviated somewhat because containerized applications are more isolated, so security attacks are less likely to affect the entire system.

Comment: How do I figure out which flatpaks are using the depreciated runtimes?

Comment: Perhaps with the flatpak info command. Otherwise, removing the outdated runtimes will remove the applications that use them.